# Filtering results from lists Python

Tags: python, dictionary, search, filter

I have been trying to find the answer around the web without any results.
I  am trying to create a system where a user can search through lists and return their subjects and grades, with a filter to only show subjects from one area (for example Informational science) and also filtering the level of the subject(if it is a 100lvl, 200lvl or 300lvl) I have tried with Sub_string but doesnt work properly.
So the view code i have so far(With sub_string) is this:

```
def finn():
    global Karakterer
    global Emner
    print("Velg fag og/eller emnenivå (<enter> for alle)")
    Fag = input("-Fag: ")
    for sub_string in Emner:
        if str(Fag) in sub_string:
         print(*([sub_string] + ([Karakterer[sub_string]] if sub_string in Karakterer else [])))
```

these are my lists (converted to Dicts for it to work)

```
Emner = ["INFO100","INFO104","INFO110","INFO150","INFO125", "RELV102"]
FagKoder = [["Informasjonsvitenskap","INF"],["Kognitiv vitenskap","Kog"], 
["Religionsvitenskap","REL"],["DigitalKultur","DIK"],["Økonomi","ECO"]]
Karakterer=[["INFO100","C"],["INFO104","B"],["INFO110","E"], ["RELV102","A"]]
Karakterer=dict(Karakterer)
FagKoder = dict(FagKoder)
```

This is how it is printed out now, and is the way i need it to be printed:

[image]

My problem is that Sub_string dosent work properly for what i need, because i need to be able to allow the user to select an Area (INFO for example) and aswell a spesific level so (level 200) and then print out all INFO subjects at level 200.
But sub_string only litteraly checks that the string is contained in the list and prints that. 
Does anyone have a better soluting?
hope that makes sense
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post the expected output as an image. Images cannot be copy/pasted, searched, etch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal fix might be to split out the number from the end and compare that separately.

```
def finn():
    global Karakterer  # ugh
    global Emner       # ugh
    want_subj = input("Velg fag (<enter> for alle): ")
    want_level = input("Velg emnenivå (<enter> for alle): ")
    try:
        want_level = int(want_level)
    except ValueError:
        want_level = None
    for subject in Emner:
        # no need for str(Fag); input by definition returns a string
        if want_subj in subject:
          if not want_level or int(subject[-3:]) == want_level:
            print(*([sub_string] + ([Karakterer[sub_string]] if sub_string in Karakterer else [])))
```

A better solution might be to store the courses and their level as separate items so you don't have to parse out the number when you need it. (As an aside, you should not assign to a list and then recast as a `dict` when you can easily define a `dict` directly.)

```
Emner = [("INFO",100),("INFO",104),("INFO",110),("INFO",150),("INFO",125, ("RELV",102)]
FagKoder = {
    "INF": "Informasjonsvitenskap",
    "Kog": "Kognitiv vitenskap",
    "REL": "Religionsvitenskap",
    "DIK": "DigitalKultur"
    "ECO": "Økonomi"
    }
```

It should be fairly obvious how to adapt the code to work with these structures instead.

(As an aside, you seem to have "RELV" in `Emner` but "REL" in `FagKoder`.)